# Finding flux of a vector field $\mathbf{F}$ across a surface bounded by an unknown function.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

A solid $\Gamma$ in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is bounded by $$0 \leq x \leq 1, \hspace{.5cm} 0 \leq y \leq 1, \hspace{.5cm} 0 \leq z \leq g(x, y),$$ where $z = g(x, y)$ is an unknown differentiable surface.

Suppose the flux of the vector field $\mathbf{F} (x, y, z) = (x, -2y, z + 3)$ across the side of $\Gamma$ which is on the plane $y = 1$ is $-3,$ and across the side of $\Gamma$ which is on the plane $x = 1$ is $1.$ Then:

(1) What is the flux of $\mathbf{F}$ across the side of $\Gamma$ which is on the plane $x = 0?$

(2) What is the flux of $\mathbf{F}$ across the side of $\Gamma$ which is on the plane $y = 0?$

---

Okay, now my work: since the flux of a vector field is defined as $$ \iint_{\Gamma} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{n} \hspace{.1cm}d\Gamma,$$ where the unit normal vector of $\Gamma,$ denoted by $\mathbf{n},$ defines the orientation on the surface, and $\Gamma$ is a closed surface, then the side of $\Gamma$ which is on the plane $x = 0$ has orientation opposite to the orientation on the side of $\Gamma$ which is on the plane $x = 1.$ Hence the answer to (1) is: $Flux = -1.$

By a similar argument the answer to (2) would be: $Flux = 3.$

Is the above reasoning correct?

Comment: Wrong, the fluxes should be zero. Note that in the first case, the normal vector is $(-1,0,0)$ and $x = 0$ over the plane. We are integrating the zero function and we get $0$. The second case is similar. Knowing that the flux through the plane $x=1$ is $1$ only tells us that $\int_{[0,1]} g(1,y)\; dy = 1$, but nothing else.

Comment: @ChrisK Does this change on the part on $\Gamma$ which is on the plane $z= 0$ and on the surface $z = g(x, y)?$

Comment: What do you mean by "does this change"? At $z=0$, we are integrating $\int_{[0,1]^2} -3\; dA = -3$, while over $z=g(x,y)$, we are integrating $\int_{[0,1]^2} g(x,y) + 3\; dA$.